# Why can't I execute Couchbase's query program cbq from home directory?

Tags: linux, centos, couchbase

I have Couchbase Community Edition 6.0.0 running on CentOS 7.

I am able to enter an interactive `cbq` shell session by changing directory to `/opt/couchbase/bin/` and executing `./cbq -u=username` as per [the documentation](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-intro/cbq.html).

I added the path `/opt/couchbase/bin/` to the `$PATH` environment variable in order to be able to execute `cbq` directly from the user home directory.

However, when I try to do so using `cbq -u=username` I get the response:

`Usage: cbq {start|compile|stop|restart|timecheck|list|stats}`

It is only when I navigate to the `bin` directory mentioned, and executing `./cbq -u=username` that I am able to run `cbq`.

Why do I have to navigate to the parent directory of `cbq` if I already added the path to `$PATH`?

Comment: Did you add `/opt/couchbase/bin/` to the *beginning* of your `$PATH` ?

Comment: I did not. I added it to the end of `$PATH` and after I added it to the beginning it worked. I found another `cbq` in `/usr/sbin` which appears earlier in `$PATH`. Thank you @dnault for pointing me in the right direction.